# React Native : want to run a function from app, and it would be not stop if app in background or foreground state

Tags: react-native, background-thread, react-native-background-fetch

I have a function that has a for loop and I trigger the APIs in the queue it's working very well but if I change my app state foreground to background my queue was paused until I reopen the app.

That function doesn't need to stop until I stop manually or all APIs hit successfully.

React native version: 0.64.2

Comment: have you tried react query ?

Comment: @heathkev react query supports for react native as well?

Comment: I am also stuck in similar kind of situation. I have tried various libraries such as "react-native-queue" , "react-native-job-queue", "react-native-background-action" etc.
But none of them works for me, they are just providing ways to run tasks in background but my requirement is that my ongoing process should run irrespective of app state changes.